# Label text not changing when it is supposed to

Tags: .net, vb.net

My full code is below. Basically when a user attempts to login, the screen shakes and a label shows "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..." first and then "Invalid Credentials" next.
After typing in incorrect credentials, what's supposed to happen is the label ONLY shows "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..." but what IS happening is that this text is never displayed and just shows my other form. I can't figure out why. Can someone help?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class frmSplash
    Dim UsernameFirstLoad As Boolean = True
    Dim PasswordFirstLoad As Boolean = True
    Dim UsernameGotFocus As Boolean = False
    Dim PasswordGotFocus As Boolean = False
    Dim UserValidated As Boolean = False
    Dim FormFirstLoad As Boolean = True
    Dim Username, Password As String

    Dim DS As New DataSet
    WithEvents credentialsBS As New BindingSource


    Private Sub frmSplash_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2B2B2B")
        lblLoginStatus.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2B2B2B")
        'lblLoginStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
        'lblLoginStatus.Text = "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..."
        Logo.Focus()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frmSplash_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Logo.Focus()
        Dim x As Integer = CInt((Panel1.Size.Width - txtUsername.Size.Width) / 2)
        Dim x2 As Integer = CInt((Panel3.Size.Width - btnLogin.Size.Width) / 2)
        With DS
            .Tables.Add(New DataTable With {.TableName = "Credentials"})
        End With

        txtUsername.Location = New Point(x, txtUsername.Location.Y)
        txtPassword.Location = New Point(x, txtPassword.Location.Y)
        Label1.Location = New Point(txtUsername.Location.X - 2, txtUsername.Location.Y - 2)
        Label2.Location = New Point(txtPassword.Location.X - 2, txtPassword.Location.Y - 2)
        btnLogin.Location = New Point(x2, btnLogin.Location.Y)
        'lblLoginStatus.Location = New Point(x2, lblLoginStatus.Location.Y)

        txtUsername.Text = "Username"
        txtPassword.Text = "Password"
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtUsername_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.Click
        If UsernameFirstLoad = True Then
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtUsername.ForeColor = Color.Black
            UsernameFirstLoad = False
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtPassword_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPassword.Click
        If PasswordFirstLoad = True Then
            txtPassword.Clear()
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = CChar("•")
            txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Black
            PasswordFirstLoad = False
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtUsername_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.GotFocus
        If UsernameGotFocus = True Then
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtUsername.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Else
            UsernameGotFocus = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtUsername_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.LostFocus
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
            txtUsername.ForeColor = Color.DimGray
            txtUsername.Text = "Username"
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtPassword_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPassword.GotFocus
        'If PasswordGotFocus = False Then
        txtPassword.Clear()
        txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Black
        txtPassword.PasswordChar = CChar("•")
        'PasswordGotFocus = True
        'End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub txtPassword_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPassword.LostFocus
        If txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.DimGray
            txtPassword.Text = "Password"
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        lblLoginStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
        lblLoginStatus.Text = "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..."
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)

        Logo.Focus()
        Username = txtUsername.Text.Trim
        Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        btnLogin.Enabled = False
        'txtUsername.ReadOnly = True
        'txtPassword.ReadOnly = True
        bwLogin.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
    Private Sub bwLogin_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwLogin.DoWork
        If FormFirstLoad = True Then
            Using MySQLConn As New MySqlConnection("server=1.1.1.1;user id=username;password=12345;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=database")
                Using loginDA As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM credentials", MySQLConn)
                    loginDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
                    loginDA.FillSchema(DS.Tables("Credentials"), SchemaType.Source)
                    loginDA.Fill(DS.Tables("Credentials"))
                End Using
            End Using
            FormFirstLoad = False
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub bwLogin_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwLogin.RunWorkerCompleted
        credentialsBS.DataSource = DS.Tables("Credentials")
        lblLoginStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
        lblLoginStatus.Text = "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..."
        lblLoginStatus.BringToFront()
        lblLoginStatus.Visible = True
        Dim idx As Integer
        Dim idy As Integer
        With credentialsBS
            idx = .Find("username", Username)
            If idx >= 0 Then
                idy = .Find("password", Password)
                If idy >= 0 Then
                    'lblLoginStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
                    'lblLoginStatus.Text = "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..."
                    LoginSuccess()
                Else
                    LoginFailed()
                End If
            Else
                LoginFailed()
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoginSuccess()
        lblLoginStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
        lblLoginStatus.Text = "Connecting to SQL. Please wait..."
        lblLoginStatus.Visible = True

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        frmMain.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoginFailed()
        'lblLoginStatus.Text = ""
        'lblLoginStatus.Visible = False
        Me.Left += 10
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Me.Left -= 10
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Me.Left += 10
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Me.Left -= 10
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)

        lblLoginStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblLoginStatus.Text = "Invalid Credentials!"
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
        btnLogin.Enabled = True
        txtUsername.ReadOnly = False
        txtPassword.ReadOnly = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have the code to show the label on the completion of your background worker...move it to just before the call to DoWork

Comment: @sidprasher Hey, thanks - I have the label showing when you click btnLogin already though, which is before the DoWork.

Comment: MSDN recommends not using GoTFocus and LostFocus "the Enter and Leave events should be used for all controls except the Form class, which uses the Activated and Deactivate events. "

Comment: @Mary Thanks Mary! I appreciate that! I changed my code :)

Comment: If I enter one person's username and another person's password will my login be successful? Check your credentials logic.

Comment: Passwords should never be stored as plain text. Instead of shaking windows research password encryption and salts.

Comment: @Mary Wow, thanks! I never would have caught the credentials thing! I've fixed it! The plain text thing - unfortunately I'm still fairly new to coding so I'm a little clueless, but I'll definitely look it up!

Comment: I have another update for your code but it is a bit much for a comment. I will post as an answer even though you have already solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need to run this Async since nothing else can happen until approval. Don't pull down all the data in the table (could be thousands of records) just to check one user. Database servers are very good at searching with indexes and all. Let the server do the work. Be sure to use parameters to avoid SQL Injection. I hope this can simplify things for you.

```
Private Sub bwLogin_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwLogin.DoWork
        Using MySQLConn As New MySqlConnection("server=1.1.1.1;user id=username;password=12345;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=database")
            'Check for the correct names of your columns in the database. Password would probably need
            'back ticks around it because it might be a reserved word.
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM credentials Where `UserName` = @User AND `Password` = @Password;", MySQLConn)
                'check the actual datatypes in your database
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim
                MySQLConn.Open()
                Dim count As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                MySQLConn.Close()
                If count = 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Success")
                    'Your success code
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Failure")
                    'Your failure code
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Mary - I finally got a chance to test your code! It looks like no matter what the count is 0 even when the credentials are correct...do you have any ideas?

Comment: Jason, I will get back to you but just got a new computer and don't have MySQL installed yet.

Comment: I see one problem in my code. I misspelled `@Password` as `@Passwod`. I got rid of the asnyc stuff and just have my code in the login button click. Check that your column names match and the data types of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Looks like just adding Me.Refresh solved the issue.